# Is it possible to copy files to the host during a multistage docker build?

Tags: docker, maven, docker-multi-stage-build

I have written the following `Dockerfile` to containerize a maven build:

```
FROM maven AS builder
WORKDIR /build
COPY . /build
RUN mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository clean test clover:instrument clover:clover clover:check findbugs:check package site

FROM amazoncorretto:8
COPY --from=builder /build/target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

The second stage copies the jar file built by the first stage so that it can be used by its `ENTRYPOINT` but I'd also like the docker host to get a copy of the entire `target` directory from the container because it holds other build artefacts like code coverage and analysis reports.

Specifically, I'd like the copy to happen as part of the `docker build -t fakefirehose .` Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "host" in this sentence?  "...I'd also like the host to get a copy of entire target directory..."